# ElasticSearch rename query value

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way in ES to change a value in a search string to some list of values? For example, if my documents have a field called `frequency` and the user searches for `monthly`, it should return any documents with `frequency` as `month`, `m`, `monthly`, etc. I can roll my own on the client side, but I seem to recall hearing that I can define these myself in ES.

(totally new to ES)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [Synonyms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-synonyms.html) functionality. It can expand your `monthly` query into so-called synonyms which you can preconfigure in advance.